# Oracle create view based on another view

Tags: oracle, view

I have create a view B, then I want to create another view A based on B. But I fail, can any one help me?

CREATE VIEW A
(  aa,  ab,  ac)
AS
SELECT
  B.ba,B.bb,SUM(B.bc) AS bcc
FROM
  B
GROUP BY
  B.ba,B.bb

the error is ora-00955

Answer (score 4):

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm).

The error you are receiving is "Name is already used by an existing object."  Make sure an object with the name `A` doesn't already exist in your database.

Answer (score 1):

However, if you want to overwrite your view, you can use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...
```